# How to start a Mongod server via Node.js?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to start the server using the mongod.js in node.js.
The example is taken from here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongod

```
function f() {
   const  Mongod  =  require('mongod');


   const  server  =  new  Mongod(9004);

   server.open((err)  =>  {
      if  (err)  {

      }
      else{
         
      }
   });
}

f();
```

But an error comes out:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn mongod ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn mongod',
  path: 'mongod',
  spawnargs: [ '--port', 9004 ]
}
```

Tell me, please

Comment: Are you sure that you have a MongoDB instance running on port 9004, just it's an unusual port to run it on? Check it's running with `sudo systemctl status mongod` and print the error to the console by updating your code like this: `if (err) { console.log(err);}`

Comment: jQueeny, I want to create a database using Node. I thought to start by running the Mongod server through the code without installing through the installer from the official site Mongo. Maybe I didn't understand the principle at all?

Comment: The source code of this package does suggest it was written to start and stop a mongod service but it was last updated 7 years ago so it's difficult to rely in it's practical use today. What did the `if (err) { console.log(err);}` log?

Comment: jQuenny, nothing.

server.open((err)  =>  {
      if  (err)  {
         // It doesn't come in here
         console.log(err);
      }
   });

Maybe there is a completely different way to do what I want?

Comment: You will still have to download install MongoDB Community on your system no matter what.

Comment: jQueeny, okay, thanks. I need a database installed inside my project. I will look for another database